# Difference in operators for PHP

Tags: php

What is the difference between `swap($a, $a)` and with an '&' added for `swap(&$a, &$a)`

```
<?php 
 function swap($x, $y) { 
 $x = $x + 1; 
 $y = $y + 2; 
 return $x * $y; 
 } 

 $a = 2; 
 $b = swap($a, $a); 
 print "$a, $b"; 
 $b = swap(&$a, &$a); 
 print "$a, $b"; 
?>
```

Note: not asking for the answer, just wrote this so i could provide an example. Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a php question?

Comment: Sorry meant to write PHP been doing javascript work all day and it messed my brain up :P

Comment: [PHP: References Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: Thanks for that list, will help a lot. Solved my question although cannot see &$ on the list

Answer (score 1):

The `&` means that the parameter is passed by reference. The question is indeed a duplicate but please be aware that you shouldn't use call-time pass-by-reference anymore.

From the [passing by reference page on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

> As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time
>   pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as
>   of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it
>   will raise a fatal error.

What you still can do is using the `&` in the function definition:

```
function swap(&$x, &$y) { 
    $x = $x + 1; 
    $y = $y + 2; 
    return $x * $y; 
}
```